# Is there a way to import XML back to JSON file in Delphi?

Tags: json, xml, delphi

Like the title, Postman imports JSON files normally
When you load a file with Delphi Get method coding,
Gets the XML format. I used the GET method code that I used well before, but I don't know what the problem is.

Oh, the source code
'idhttps.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('ContentType:application/json');' was added because the other side set it this way. :(

※I am very sorry that I asked you a question using a translator because I am a Korean who can't speak English well.

```pascal
begin
            idhttps := TIdHTTP.Create;
            //===========================idhttp Get=========================
            try

          //Edit1.text := Base64Encode(Edit1.Text);    //Edit1.Text값을 Base64값으로 변경
          //EditBASE64.Text := stringreplace(edit1.Text,'+','%2B',[rfReplaceAll]); //+ 공백오류로인한 문자열변환

            APIURL := 'URL'; //API URL

            //======================SSL 처리============================
            sslIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(idhttps);
            sslIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
            sslIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
            idhttps.IOHandler := sslIOHandler;
//======================SSL 처리 끝============================
//======================idhttp================================
            idHttps.Request.Clear;
            idhttps.Request.Method:='GET';
            idhttps.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
            idhttps.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('ContentType:application/json');
            idhttps.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('keycode:ACCESSCODE');
            idhttps.HandleRedirects := False;
            idhttps.ConnectTimeout := 10000;
            idhttps.ReadTimeout := 10000;
//======================idhttp================================          

            //======================UTF-8설정=============================
            idHttps.Request.AcceptCharSet := 'utf-8';
           //======================UTF-8설정 끝=============================
            idhttps.HTTPOptions := idhttps.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
            lstream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8); // TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
            idhttps.Get(APIURL, lStream);
            Result := (lStream.DataString);
          finally

            idhttps.Free; //개체에서 메모리해체
          end;
          Edit4.Text := Result;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `Accept` header in your request (not `Content-Type`) and send `application/json`. I have also seen `text/json` used, too.

Comment: Wow, Geoff Smith, thank you so much. I wrote it down as you said, and it worked out Have a nice day Geoff Smith

Comment: MIME type `text/json` is wrong, tho - don't follow fools using that - [it's `application/json` as per RFC 8259 § 11.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-11).

Comment: tahsnk @amjgojack